# Adding points limits

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics

With 4 points I set a path where your total length was subdivided into 300 points

```
Clear["Global`*"]  
points={{0,0},{5,8.07774721},{10,4.24499363},{20,9.28880172}}  
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]  

n=300;  
pts=LineScaledCoordinate[points,N@(#/n)]&/@Range[0,n];
```

However with this code were not included in the list `points`. Then with the function below I've added.

```
pts=Insert[pts,points[[2]],107];  
pts=Insert[pts,points[[3]],177];
```

I added these points in the correct position because I searched by hand and applied the function.
This is the first question:
**How do you find these positions in an automatic way?**

With that done, with these new items i created divisions where these points are at the end of each list.
**How could I do that these points are reference for these divisions?**

```
list1=pts[[#,1]]&/@Range[107];  
list2=pts[[#,1]]&/@Range[108,177];  
list3=pts[[#,1]]&/@Range[178,303];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a answer based on the solution of [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128462/adding-points-limits/128463#128463).

I would like to offer my attempts without damaging the response that does not belong to me.

**My attempts**

Here is the list pts without the values from the list points

```
Clear["Global`*"]
points = {{0, 0}, {5, 8.07774721}, {10, 4.24499363}, {20, 9.28880172}};
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]

n = 300;
pts = LineScaledCoordinate[points, N@(#/n)] & /@ Range[0, n];
```

With the function below it is possible to structure the points from the list points in pairs with offset value 1.

```
Partition[points, 2, 1]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{0,0\} & \{5,8.07775\} \\
>  \{5,8.07775\} & \{10,4.24499\} \\
>  \{10,4.24499\} & \{20,9.2888\} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

With the function below it is possible to get the lengths between the pairs mentioned above

```
partialPath = EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[points, 2, 1] // N
```

[image]

> $\{9.5,6.3,11.2\}$

With the function below it is possible to make the accumulated form sum

```
Accumulate[partialPath]
```

> $\{9.5,15.8,27.\}$

With the function below it is possible to delete the last element of the accumulated numbers list

```
Most@Accumulate[partialPath]
```

> $\{9.5,15.8\}$

With the function below it is possible to use the last element of the accumulated numbers list

```
Last@Accumulate[partialPath]
```

> $27$

With the function below it is possible to get the percentage of each path with the full path

```
porcentPath = {#/Last@Accumulate[partialPath]} & /@Most@Accumulate[partialPath]
```

[image]

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0.351852 \\
>  0.585185 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

With the function below, it is possible to separate the points in the points list that are not included in the pts list

```
valuesPositions = Rest@Most@points
```

[image]

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  5 & 8.07775 \\
>  10 & 4.24499 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

With the function below it is possible to identify which positions in should be inserted the values {5,8.07774721} and {10,4.24499363}

```
pos = Flatten@Transpose[Ceiling[n*porcentPath] + 1]
```

[image]

> $\{107,177\}$

With the function below it is possible to define a list to be added values, the values to be added and the positions they should be inserted.

```
InsertValuePosition[list_, values_, positions_] := 
 Fold[Insert[#, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]] &, list, Transpose[{values, positions}]]
pts = InsertValuePosition[pts, valuesPositions, Transpose[{pos}]]
```

With the function below it is possible to subdivide the pts list in three other lists where the entered values are at the end of the two first lists

```
FoldPairList[TakeDrop, pts, Flatten@{0, pos, Length@pts} // Differences]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Nearest[pts ->Automatic] /@ points (*thanks: MichaelE2 *)
```

> {{1}, {107}, {177}, {301}}

```
pointsandpos = Thread[{points[[2 ;; -2]], {0, 1} + 
    Flatten[Nearest[pts -> Automatic] /@ points[[2 ;; -2]]]}];

newpts = Fold[Insert[#, ## & @@ #2] &, pts, pointsandpos];

ListPlot[{points, newpts}, Joined -> { False, True}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `Nearest[pts -> Automatic]` is more efficient.

Comment: It's unclear, I guess, whether the index returned is before or after the vertex.

Comment: @kglr I made a test with your answer and appears duplicate points

Comment: @kglr Test: `Position[newpts, 5]` and `Position[newpts, 10]`

Comment: What I meant about the index is that in the OP's example the two interior indices returned by `Nearest`, `{107}, {177}`, are points that come just after the nearest vertex (`points[[2]], points[[3]` resp.). In another configuration, they might come before depending on the nearest point to the vertex. Then the offsets you add, `{0, 1}`, to get `pointsandpos` would have to be changed. I doubt that even `Nearest[..][p, 2]` would bracket the point `p`. Think of a tall narrow "W."

Answer (score 2):

The "positions" of the corners can be found as follows;

```
distances = Accumulate[EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[points, 2, 1]];
pos = 1 + n*Most[distances]/Last[distances]
(*  {106.556, 176.556}  *)
```

The fractional part can be interpreted as a interpolation between the points with positions `{{106}, {107}}` and `{{176}, {177}}` respectively.  The vertices can be inserted, therefore, between them.

To split the list `pts`, maybe this?

```
lists = {list1, list2, list3} = 
  pts[[#]] & /@ 
   Rest@FoldList[Span[#[[-1]] + 1, #2] &, {0}, Append[Floor[pos], n + 1]];

gpts = Thread@{{Red, Green, Blue}, Point /@ lists}; (* graphics for pts *)
Graphics[{
  gpts,
  Black, PointSize@Medium, Point[points[[2 ;; 3]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For just the first coordinate, change `pts[[#]]` to `pts[[#, 1]]`.

---

Alternatively, you can use `LineScaledCoordinate` to get the equally spaced points together with `points`, in case that is desired:

```
pts2 = LineScaledCoordinate[points, #] & /@ 
  Union[Range[0., 300]/n, Most[distances]/Last[distances]];

Position[pts2, p_ /; AnyTrue[points, p == # &]]
(*  {{1}, {107}, {178}, {303}}  *)
```

---

*Update:* If you want the 2nd and 3rd points appended to the ends of the first two segments...

First note I added `lists = {list1, list2, list3}` to the original answer above. It's not clear to me whether a list of lists or the separate lists is a better data structure for the actual use case, so I'll show both simulatneously.

Next note that the code correctly splits `pts` at `points`:

```
GraphicsRow[
 Graphics[{Line[points], PointSize[Large], gpts},
    PlotRange -> Outer[Plus, #, {-0.2, 0.2}]] & /@ points[[2 ;; 3]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The easiest way to append a couple of points is to `Append` them.

```
(* append points[[2]], points[[3]] and update the lists *)
lists[[1 ;; 2]] = {list1, list2} =
   MapThread[Append, {Most@lists, points[[2 ;; 3]]}];
gpts = Thread@{{Red, Green, Blue}, Point /@ lists};   (* update graphics *)
GraphicsRow[
 Graphics[{Line[points], PointSize[Large], gpts},
    PlotRange -> Outer[Plus, #, {-0.2, 0.2}]] & /@ points[[2 ;; 3]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the OP doesn't show this, but one might want to prepend the endpoint(s) of the (middle) segment(s) as well.  For that there's `Prepend[]`....

Comment: @LMC I don't think `Ceiling[pos]` is right: it gives http://i.stack.imgur.com/4JUmV.png -- Please explain further what's wrong with `Floor[pos]`; otherwise, `Floor` seems correct and I will roll back.

Comment: @LMC I appreciate your intention, but please test your "fixes" first. So far, none of them has done what you want.  The last one produces an error.