# Sublist as a function of positions

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list as follows:

```
listJP=Range[50]
```

> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50}

And I have another list indicating the positions where I want to create sublists

```
pos={5,12,24,38}
```

> {5,12,24,38}

The values in the above list serve to show what position the list must quit and continue the next.

```
{list1,list2,list3,list4,list5}=listJP[[#]]&/@Rest@FoldList[Span[#[[-1]]+1,#2]&,{0},Append[Flatten[pos],Length[listJP]]]
```

> {{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},{25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38},{39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50}}

This was a very good solution created by [@Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128462/adding-points-limits/128463#128463), but the Slot function still confuse me and so I would know if there is an in-built to do that.

I looked for something in `Split`, `Partition`, `SpliBy`, but unfortunately I did not succeed.

Comment: I feel like this is a duplicate. I'll search for it. But here: ``Internal`PartitionRagged[listJP, 
 Prepend[Differences@Append[pos, Length@listJP], First@pos]]``.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
FoldPairList[TakeDrop, listJP, Flatten@{0, pos, Length@listJP} // Differences]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
>     19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 
>     35, 36, 37, 38}, {39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50}}

**UPDATE**

These are the steps in the process:

`FoldPairList[TakeDrop,listJP,Flatten@{0,pos,Length@listJP}//Differences]
 FoldPairList[TakeDrop,listJP,Flatten@{0,{5,12,24,38},50}//Differences]
 FoldPairList[TakeDrop,listJP,{0,5,12,24,38,50}//Differences]
 FoldPairList[TakeDrop,listJP,{5,7,12,14,12}]`

Now is simple: the list will be subdivided into sublists with the lengths above. Takes the First 5, then 7, then the 12 ...

The code above uses the positions to define the lengths that the function needs.

And `Length@listJP` ensures that will be used the elements of the list mentioned

Comment: Thus it is more simplified so I understand better.

Comment: I found it very interesting this new command, but it is well complex for me. But at least it has little Slot. I tried to understand this test and couldn't: `p = Span;
q = Plus;
FoldPairList[{p[#1, #2], q[#1, #2]} &, u, {a, b, c, d}]`

Comment: I managed to find in the documentation the reference that possibly you have used: `FoldPairList[TakeDrop, {a, b, c, d, e, f}, {1, 3, 2}]`

Comment: @JPeter Now we have a function without `Slot`

Answer (score 7):

With `pos = {5, 12, 24, 38}`, this will work:

```
Split[listJP, FreeQ[pos, #] &]
```

or (the same reasoning, but reversed)

```
Split[listJP, Not @ MemberQ[pos, #] &]
```

---

Or with `PartitionRagged`, an undocumented yet useful command:

```
pos = {0}~Join~pos~Join~{Length @ listJP}
```

or

```
pos = Join[{0}, pos, {Length @ listJP}]
(* or just: pos = Flatten @ {0, pos, Length @ listJP} *)

Internal`PartitionRagged[listJP, Differences @ pos]
```

Comment: I carelessly did not see your answer uses the same method. I will delete mine. Apologies.

Answer (score 5):

Mapping on Maps... (but uses slots)

```
listJP[[Span @@ #]] & /@ ({#[[1]] + 1, #[[2]]} & /@ 
 Partition[Flatten[{0, pos, Length@listJP}], 2, 1])
```

Answer (score 3):

The function `dPcore` used in my answer to [Partitioning with varying partition size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/partitioning-with-varying-partition-size/7512#7512) does just this:

```
dPcore[listJP, pos, All]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
>  {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12},
>  {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24},
>  {25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38},
>  {39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using `TakeList` (since V 11.2) and `Splice` (since V 12.1):

```
list = Range[50];
pos = {5, 12, 24, 38};

TakeList[list, Differences[{0, Splice @ pos, Length @ list}]]
```

{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34,
35, 36, 37, 38}, {39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50}}